# Nginx: Unable to upload file > 10MB. Client intended to send too large body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I've deployed my Rails application in Ubuntu 12.04 using `nginx` and `unicorn`.

In my application I'm unable to upload file of size grater than 10MB. I've checked `nginx` error log and found

```
client intended to send too large body
```

I've googled and got a solution that I have to add `client_max_body_size 25M;` to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. I did so, but it's not working. Please help. Below added `nginx.conf` contents:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 25M;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css text/comma-separated-values;
        upstream app_server { server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;}

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 4):

In **nginx.conf** add this line in server block:--

```
http {
 #other configuration
 server {
    #other configuration
    client_max_body_size 25M;
 }
}
```

Add this in **http block** :--

```
server {
listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 25M;
    server_name localurl.me;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. okay, what would be other configuration inside this server context?

Comment: other configuration means it has already some other settings in both block which should be left as it is or you can customize accordingly.

Comment: but my `nginx.conf` doesn't have any `server` context. what sould I do please help.